# cifs.ko wanted for MTK 6572 device

Tags: networking

I want to access my external HD attached to Raspberry PI, so I've installed SMB server on it, and CifsManger on my MTK6572 device (rooted, busybox installed). I've tested the SMB server with my desktop machine, and it works.

CifsManager says that I have to install **cifs.ko**. I have downloaded one and copied to the device, but insmod says:

```
# /system/bin/insmod cifs.ko                          
insmod: init_module 'cifs.ko' failed (Exec format error)
```

I've tried ones from other sources, but the result is the same.

My configuration:

```
# cat /proc/cpuinfo                                   
Processor   : ARMv7 Processor rev 3 (v7l)
```

Kernel version is 3.4.5.

I'm not sticked to CifsManager, I just want to mount the HD on my device, so all programs should use it. (File managers can see SMB and SSH servers, but they don't mount.) I can install any file server service on the Raspberry Pi.

**EDIT:** I've used `file` command to determine the exact type of my existing `.ko` modules:

```
$ file /media/peklapat/system/lib/modules/devapc.ko 
  /media/peklapat/system/lib/modules/devapc.ko: 
  ELF 32-bit LSB relocatable, ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV),
  BuildID[sha1]=*cut*, not stripped
```

**Edit2**: Modinfo says:

```
  $ modinfo /media/peklapat/system/lib/modules/wlan_mt6582.ko 
    filename:       /media/peklapat/system/lib/modules/wlan_mt6582.ko
    license:        GPL
    description:    NIC_DESC
    author:         NIC_AUTHOR
    depends:        mtk_stp_wmt
    intree:         Y
    vermagic:       3.4.5 SMP preempt mod_unload ARMv7
```

Comment: Do you have kernel source for mtk6572 device?

Comment: Nope. But MTK6572 is not a rare animal, lot of phones, tablets and TV sticks are equipped with it.

Comment: try this one http://forum.xda-developers.com/attachment.php?attachmentid=1764228&d=1361929447 might work for you

Comment: Nope. I've used `file` to determine exact type of my `.ko` files, I added this info in the question. Anyway, thanks!

Comment: Hm, `file` says the same for the `.ko`-s you've sent, why `insmod` keeps saying the same error (Exec format error)?

Comment: could you provide the kernel log output: "dmesg" after trying to insmod your module? This usually contains valuable hints when stumbling over such problems.

Comment: <3>[517515.694103] (0)[29512:insmod]cifs: version magic '3.1.10-g05b777c SMP preempt mod_unload ARMv7 ' should be '3.4.5 SMP preempt mod_unload ARMv7 '
<7>[517515.701031] (0)[29512:insmod][29512:insmod] exit
<7>[517515.701540] (0)[29512:insmod][29512:insmod] sig 17 to [29446:sh]
<7>[517515.702140] (0)[29446:sh][29446:sh] fork [29513:sh]